# Maximum Number with this condition satisified

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Given an array $A$ of $N$ elements $A[1],A[2],A[3]...A[n]$, I need to find maximum element in the array such that $GCD(G,A[i]) > 1$ for given $G$ and $1\leq i\leq N$.

Example : Let we have $N=6$ and array be $[1,2,3,4,5,4]$ and let $G$ be $2$ then here answer is $4$.

Explanation :

```
GCD(2,1)=1
GCD(2,2)=2
GCD(2,3)=1
GCD(2,4)=2
GCD(2,5)=1
GCD(2,4)=2
```

So maximum is $4$ here.

Comment: How is the maximum $4$ if $GCD(G, A[3])$ is not greater than $1$?

Comment: @5xum Out of 2,4,4 the maximum is 4 so the answer is 4

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just calculate $GCD(G, A[i])$ for all  values of $i$?

**Edit**:
If the array $A$ is fixed, then the best path I see is the one you already mentioned, that is, find all prime divisors of $A[i]$ for each $i$. You do not even need the full prime factorisation, only a list of prime numbers dividing each number.

Another optimisation off the top is that you can first sort the array $A$ from largest to smallest and remove duplicates, so that $A[1]> A[2]>A[3]>\dots$.

Now, when you get a number $G$ first check if any prime divisors of $A[i]$ also divide $G$. If one does, then $A[1]$ is the answer. If not, repeat with $A[2]$ and so on.

Comment: Suppose i have 10^5 numbers and say i need to find this in a range from [L,R] then finding it for each query seperately is so inefficient.I am searching for some better way.

Comment: Well, you will have to inspect each number at least once (as long as you have no other facts known about $A$). A quick optimisation is that if your running maximum is larger or equal to $A[i]$, then the calculation of $GCD(G,A[i])$ is not necesary.

Comment: All A[i]<=100000.I think prime factorising earlier each number before querying can help in some way.What you say?

Comment: I don't agree. For example, if $G=1000$ and $A[1] = 1000$, while $A[i] = 999$ for all $i>1$, so if you factorize each $A[i]$, you will do a lot of unnecessary work, when you just have to see that $GCD(G,A[1])> A[i]$ for all $i>1$. Anyway, for calculating $GCD$, I suggest Euclid's algorithm.

Comment: But it will help in handling query in range.You are talking of worst case here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, I am not talking of worst case, I think prime factorisation is unnecesary in any case, since Euclid is much faster. In the time you need to factorize $A[i]$, you can easily calculate $GCD(G, A[i])$.
@amWhy Actually, it is an answer, it is the answer of "make one for loop throuh the array $A$."

Comment: @5xum calculating it again and again for each query is inefficient.so your answer is not what i want

Comment: Yes, well, if $A$ is fixed and you need to calculate the maximum for several values of $G$ and the same array $A$, you are right. Of course, had you mentioned that at the beginning, I would not have posted my answers (optimised for *one* run). See, this is why we always point out that questions need to be well written. I suggest you edit your question to show what your real goal is.

Comment: I edited my answer.